# D7 - syntax in Field template

Tags: theming

My D7 content type has a field for an MP3 file. I want the field to display as an image which the user can then right click to download the file ie like [this](http://desertcow.co.uk/file.html). My field template file looks like this:

```
var_dump($items) =

<div style="border:10px solid violet;padding:4px; margin-bottom:10px">
<?php var_dump($items); ?>
</div>

print_r($form) = 

<div style="border:10px solid maroon;padding:4px; margin-bottom:10px">
<?php print_r($items); ?>
</div>

<div style="border:10px solid orange; margin-bottom:20px">    

<?php echo $items[filesize]; ?>
<?php echo $items['filesize']; ?>
<?php echo $items["filename"]; ?>
<?php echo $items['url']; ?>
<?php echo $items['uri']; ?>
</div>

<div style="border:10px solid green;margin-bottom:20px">
<a href="<?php echo $items['url']; ?>"><img src="/download.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

The result is [here](http://desertcow.co.uk/test). 
Can anyone please tell me why the orange box is empty / not printing out, and the correct syntax re the green box to make the image link to the MP3 file URL instead of the page URL?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are printing wrong the array $items. It should be something like

```
print $items['#file']->filename;
```

The same is happening with the image issue.

Comment: thanks - I tried your suggestion but the variables are still not printing (orange box is still empty) - I have added the updated field template file to the page = http://desertcow.co.uk/test

Comment: Can you install devel module and the use dpm($items) in order to see the results? With dpm() is easier to see arrays and objects.

Comment: I have added dpm($items) = http://desertcow.co.uk/test - does that help? Thanks...

Comment: Why the dmp result is different from the screenshot you took? In any case where are you printing this, node.tpl.php or page.tpl.php?

Comment: The dpm is in my field template file - see red arrow here  http://i.imgur.com/Fl4QwyS.jpg and also http://i.imgur.com/w2SlYYY.jpg . I am not sure why http://i.imgur.com/Fl4QwyS.jpg is different to http://desertcow.co.uk/sites/default/files/images/dpm2.jpg Thanks...

Comment: can you print in field--field-mp3-download.tpl.php this:  print $items[0]['#file']->filename;
It will return the filename, but if you need the path, you will have to something like:
$path = $items[0]['#file']->uri;
print file_create_url($path);

Comment: the variables are now printing, thank you. But the image link is not right. I tried this <?php $path = $items[0]['#file']->uri; ?> 
<a href="<?php print $path; ?>"><img src="/download.jpg"></a> - any ideas please? Thanks...

Comment: You are doing it right, just have to use: print file_create_url($path);
Actually, in the last instruction of the orange box you are print the path correctly and it shows http://desertcow.co.uk/sites/default/files/MP3/HoP%20090%20A%20Decorated%20Corpse%20Plotinus%20on%20Matter%20and%20Evil.mp3

Comment: Yes but I mean the link does not work in the download image (green box) = bottom of field template file here http://desertcow.co.uk/sites/default/files/images/field-template.jpg Thanks...

Comment: Yes because in the green box you have <a href="<?php print path; ?>"> and it should be <a href="<?php print file_create_url($path); ?>">

Comment: misión cumplida. Muchas gracias por su ayuda y su paciencia. :)

Comment: You are welcome :), by the way you can check the answer as correct :)